# WP update_post_meta not updating

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I can't seem to get the values to update correctly. They initially save data when entered when creating the post, but will not update afterward. I've looked everywhere but have found no answers. Can anyone tell what's wrong? All help is appreciated.

```
function casestudy_save_meta($post_id, $post) {

    global $post;

    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post->ID ))
        return $post->ID;

    // Put it into an array to make it easier to loop though.
    $casestudy_meta['link'] = $_POST['link'];

    foreach ($casestudy_meta as $key => $value) {

        if( $post->post_type == 'casestudy' ) return;
        // Don't store custom data twice
        $value = implode(',', (array)$value);
        if(get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, FALSE)) {
            // If the custom field already has a value
            update_post_meta($post->ID, $key, $value);
        } else {
            // If the custom field doesn't have a value
            add_post_meta($post->ID, $key, $value);
        }
        if(!$value) delete_post_meta($post->ID, $key);
    }
}
add_action('save_post', 'casestudy_save_meta', 1, 2);
```

Comment: try casestudy_save_meta($post_id) instead of casestudy_save_meta($post_id, $post)

Comment: Nope. Not it. Removing $post does not do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've decided to pull it out of the array and just do it this way. It works if anyone else needs a little help with the same problem.

```
function casestudy_save_meta($post_id, $post) {

    if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['casestudy_meta_noncename'], plugin_basename(__FILE__) )) {
        return $post->ID;
    }

    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post->ID )) {
        return $post->ID;
    }

    // Update, add, or delete field ----------------------------------
    if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'link', FALSE ) ) {
        update_post_meta($post->ID, 'link', $_POST['link']);
    } else {
        add_post_meta($post->ID, 'link', $_POST['link']);
    }
    if ( $_POST['link'] == '' ) {
        delete_post_meta($post->ID, 'link');
    }

}
add_action('save_post', 'casestudy_save_meta', 1, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the notation you use to convert to an array.

You could try this instead...

```
// Put it into an array to make it easier to loop though.
$casestudy_meta = array(
    'link' => $_POST['link']
);
```

or in this case, even...

```
// Put it into an array to make it easier to loop though.
$casestudy_meta = array_intersect_key( $_POST, array_flip( array( 'link' ) ) )
```